# Storyboard Assistant Editor will not automatically switch after duplicating a ViewController

Tags: swift, duplicates, editor, xcode9.4, assistant

I have a storyboard with 6 view controllers.  I want to duplicate one of them (I essentially want to cut half the functionality out of the original VC and put that into the second VC.

In the storyboard a copy/pasted the existing VC1.  In Finder, I copy/pasted the .swift file of VC1 to a new file that I called VC2.  Back in Xcode 9.4.1, I added that VC2 file to the folder in the left hand nav pane. I clicked on VC2 in the storyboard and changed its custom class to VC2.

VC1 has a custom class of VC1 and even a StoryboardID of VC1.  VC2 has a custom class of VC2 and even a StoryboardID of VC2.  I thought the StoryboardIDs would help fix this situation.

In the Storyboard, I can clearly see VC1 and VC2.  They are labeled appropriately.  Even the window pane to the immediate left is fine!

In the Storyboard, if I click on VC2, the Assistant Editor automatically switches to VC2 and I see the code.

But... in the Storyboard if I click on VC1, then the Assistant Editor does not switch to VC1.  I have to click the word/button: Automatic, which now says (2) and choose VC1, then it will switch the code to VC1, but then I have to click VC1 again in order to have the identity inspection to list the correct stuff.

I have clicked Product -> Clean and then Product -> Build and then restarted, but it doesn't change anything

I know that I still have to cut up and edit my VC's, but the app is working (VC2 isn't segued in yet).

Can we duplicate VCs this way?  Is there a way to get the automatic assistant editing to switch accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the VC2 .swift file. Create a brand new VC2 .swift file, then copy and paste the CODE ONLY. This should avoid Xcode getting confused between VC1 and VC2.